# How to install GPSD on Gentoo

Tags: gps, gentoo, gpsd

I tried installing GPSD on Gentoo by using this command

`emerge -av gpsd`

but I keep getting error saying gpsd has unmet requirements listing down things I already installed.

may I know how can I overcome this problem?

I have been looking for the solution in the internet but it seems like no posts could help with this.

Thank you.

Comment: What does it say is *unmet*?

Comment: Can you add the messages from emerge? You may need to unmask some packages.

Comment: the messages stated : the ebuild selected to satisfy "gpsd" has unmet requirements :
-sci-geosciences/gpsd-3.9-r1::gentoo USE="X bluetooth cxx dbus ipv6 ncurses (policykit) qt4 shm sockets udev usb debug -timing -ntp -python -systemd -test" ABI_X86="64" GPSD_PROTOCOLS="aivdm ashtech earthmate evermore fv18 garmin garmintxt gpscio itrax mtk3301 navcom nmea ntrip oceanserver oncore rtmcm104v2 rtcm104v3 sirf supertar2 tnt tripmate tsip ubx -fury -geostar -nmea2000"

Comment: cont : The following REQUIRED_USE flag constraints are unsatisfied: X? (python)

The above constraints are a subset of the following complete expression: X? (python) gpsd_protocols_nmea2000? (gpsd_protocols_aivdm)

Comment: You should put the complete output of the console in your question. You can do this by pressing the edit link. I believe there should be a message about using --autounmask-write. Also with -a you should get a prompt to change your use flags [yes/no]. Is any of this showing?

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it looks like required use flags are not being met. Try running

```
emerge --autounmask-write gpsd
```

This will stage changes to the package.use file. To write these changes run

```
dispatch-conf
```

read each change and press `u` to use those changes.

Once the use flags are set correctly try to install gpsd again

```
emerge -av gpsd
```